# How to make Rhythmbox use Notification Area instead of Indicator Applet

Tags: indicator, notification, rhythmbox

Is there a way to install the pre-10.04 style Notification thing for Rhythmbox and ensure that it doesn't show up in the Indicator Applet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 10.10 Rhythmbox uses the tray icon again. So if you upgrade to 10.10, the problem will take care of itself.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to avoid an upgrade as I've got a pretty gnarly install (luks, etc). I'll go for it in a month or so when things have settled down a little. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

In Rhythmbox, go to Edit > Plugins, and find the Status Icon plugin. Click configure. Change the Status Icon from "Never Visible" to "Always Visible." There are some other options there that you can play around with as well.

I'm not quite sure about how to remove it from the Sound Menu (I'm assuming you're talking about showing up when you click the Volume icon), but I would like to know the answer to this as well.

Comment: Alas, the Status Icon plugin refers to the Indicator Applet rather than using the Notification area, so this doesn't solve the problem. The crux of the issue is that I want the player to show/hide on left click and player controls to be available on right click, as it was in Karmic and below.

Comment: @Kin that behaviour is being deprecated and the notification area may be completely removed in 11.04 -- just so you know.